# PyMC3: Retreiving "predictions" from Gaussian Process regression

Tags: python, process, regression, gaussian, pymc3

I am attempting to use `PyMC3` to fit a Gaussian Process regressor to some basic financial time series data in order to predict the next days "price" given past prices. However I'm running into issues when I try to form a prediction from the fitted GP.

Please forgive me if this has been covered elsewhere; I've done a fair bit of digging and searching but was unable to come up with a solution despite working from various related tutorials on GP regression with `PyMC3`.

The time series has been transformed to make to it stationary (in a sense), by taking the natural log of the daily prices, then applying `detrend` from `statsmodels.tsa.tsatools`.

The input X variables are 6 dimensional (6 past prices), here is an example for one datapoint:

```
In: X[0]

Out: array([ 0.02824104,  0.02591076,  0.00990705,  0.00150235,  0.01375847,
        0.02963981])
```

With the associated y variable being the next days price:

```
In: y[0]

Out: array([ 0.01260668])
```

The code where I fit the GP is thus:

```
import pymc3 as pm

with pm.Model() as gp_fit:

    # Prior beliefs in hyperparameter values (they're Gamma distributed as specified) for Matern 3/2 kernel 
    ρ = pm.Gamma('ρ', 1, 1)
    η = pm.Gamma('η', 1, 1)

    # The input is 6 dimensional hence Matern32(6, ρ)
    K = η * pm.gp.cov.Matern32(6, ρ)

    # Prior belief in mean of the Gaussian Process (it's zero)
    M = pm.gp.mean.Zero()

    # Prior noise belief (Standard Normal, 0 mean, unit variance)
    σ = pm.Normal('σ', 0, 1)

    # Fit to first 20 data points
    y_obs = pm.gp.GP('y_obs', mean_func=M, cov_func=K, sigma=σ, observed={'X':X[:20], 'Y':y[:20]})

    trace = pm.sample(2000, n_init=40000)
```

Which gives the output (with some warnings):

```
Auto-assigning NUTS sampler...
Initializing NUTS using ADVI...
Average Loss = -2,456.9:  83%|████████▎ | 33167/40000 [00:38<00:06, 1133.80it/s]
Convergence archived at 33200
Interrupted at 33,200 [83%]: Average Loss = -1,467.9
100%|█████████▉| 2499/2500 [17:29<00:00, 15.29it/s] /home/bango/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymc3/step_methods/hmc/nuts.py:448: UserWarning:     Chain 0 reached the maximum tree depth. Increase max_treedepth, increase target_accept or reparameterize.
  'reparameterize.' % self._chain_id)
/home/bango/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymc3/step_methods/hmc/nuts.py:440: UserWarning: The acceptance probability in chain 0 does not match the target. It is 0.18543857929, but should be close to 0.8. Try to increase the number of tuning steps.
  % (self._chain_id, mean_accept, target_accept))
100%|██████████| 2500/2500 [17:29<00:00,  2.38it/s]
```

Subsequently, I try to get a predicted y value from the fitted GP (given some new observation) by:

```
# Get the features of a single data point and rehape to (1,6)
X_test = X[20][None,:]

with gp_fit:
    gp_samples = pm.gp.sample_gp(trace, y_obs, X_test, samples=50, random_seed=666, progressbar=False)
```

But run into:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-9eaebf0e139a> in <module>()
      1 with gp_fit:
----> 2     gp_samples = pm.gp.sample_gp(trace, y_obs, Z, samples=50, random_seed=666, progressbar=False)

~/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymc3/gp/gp.py in sample_gp(trace, gp, X_values, samples, obs_noise, model, random_seed, progressbar)
    139     gp_post = MvNormal.dist(m_post, S_post, shape=Z.shape[0])
    140 
--> 141     samples = [gp_post.random(point=trace[idx]) for idx in indices]
    142 
    143     return np.array(samples)

~/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymc3/gp/gp.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    139     gp_post = MvNormal.dist(m_post, S_post, shape=Z.shape[0])
    140 
--> 141     samples = [gp_post.random(point=trace[idx]) for idx in indices]
    142 
    143     return np.array(samples)

~/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymc3/distributions/multivariate.py in random(self, point, size)
    156             mu, cov = draw_values([self.mu, self.cov], point=point)
    157             if mu.shape != cov[0].shape:
--> 158                 raise ValueError("Shapes for mu an cov don't match")
    159 
    160             try:

ValueError: Shapes for mu an cov don't match
```

I've dug around for a while but am presently unable to pick apart the error and rectify it. I'm not entirely sure what mu and cov matrices are being referred to.

Your help with this is greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you provide a data file (or example data) so that we can try to reproduce your error?

Comment: @bsmith89 thank you for looking, here is the data: https://www.dropbox.com/s/m2rv69f23ay6ri5/SPdata.xls?dl=0

Comment: it looks like you've shared your raw data.  I was hoping to get hold of the contents of your `X` and `y` variables (processed data), so that I could run your example code.

Comment: @bsmith89 my bad, I will sort out some approriate data and get back to you. Thanks!